# Binding variable to [value] in Reactive Forms, Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-reactive-forms, angular-ngmodel, angular-forms

```html
<form [formGroup]="form"#postForm="ngForm" (submit)="onSaveTicket()">
  <div class="text-editor-container">
    <div *textEditor="let btnClick = controller; let divField">
      <div class="text-editor__inputContainer">
        <div #myDiv id="divContenteditable" contenteditable="true" [innerHtml]="editedTicket?.description">
          Please enter a description
        </div>

        <mat-form-field>
          <textarea 
             matInput
             type="text"
             formControlName="description"
             required
             [ngModel] = "divField"
             placeholder="Description">
          </textarea>
          <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('description').invalid">Please enter a description</mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button mat-raised-button type="submit" class="btn--cyan">Add Ticket</button>
</form>
```

In code above, I have a directive *textEditor, which reads content of `div id="divContenteditable"` and returns it with the variable `divField`. Then I want to bind this variable to the value of invisible textarea, and read it in the component.

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.form = new FormGroup({
    description: new FormControl(null, {validators: [Validators.required]})
  });

  this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
    console.log(val);
  })
}
```

When i pass variable as a `[ngModel] = "divField"` instead of `[value] = "divField"`, everything works fine, but I get a warning:

"It looks like you're using ngModel on the same form field as formControlName..."

How can I obtain this result with Reactive Forms approach without the use of ngModel, which causes warning?

Comment: Please remove all code that has nothing to do with this issue (basically all but form elements)

Answer (score 0):

You should only bind the `<textarea>` using either one of them (`[ngModel]` or `formControlName`), not both. Is there a particular reason you're using both? you can remove [ngModel] and solely use formControlName and get or set the value using `form.get("description").value` or set the value using `form.get("description").setValue(".....")`.

The other option would be:

```
<div #myDiv id="divContenteditable" (change)=contentChange($event)>
   Please enter a description
</div>

contentChange(event: any){
   console.log(event.value)
   form.get("description").setValue(".....")
}
```

Comment: I need to copy data from div[contenteditable] to the form - textarea. When I bind variable containing content of div to the [value] field of textarea, angular does not see changes (in valueChanges subscription). When I use ngModel, angular sees changes. Now I am trying to find out how to replace ngModel.

Comment: I deleted unnecessary code, additionally to correct previous comment, I need to pass variable divField from directive to the value of textarea, not content of contenteditable div directly.